# Change values in a matrix non-destructively

Tags: matlab, matrix

Assume that `B` is some large matrix with integers, both zero and non-zero. I want to call the function `my_function` with B as an argument, but with the zero-values set to 1. Is there a way to do that without creating a temporary variable, as `A` in this case?

```
A = B;
A(A==0) = 1;
my_function( A );
```

Comment: Did you mean to put my_function( A )? Otherwise i dont understand the need for the first two lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in this specific case it *is* possible with the expression `B + ~B`.

#### Example

```
>> B = fix(5 * rand(5))

B =
  4  0  3  2  3
  0  3  3  0  2
  1  4  0  0  2
  1  4  3  4  3
  3  1  1  1  1

>> B + ~B

ans =
  4  1  3  2  3
  1  3  3  1  2
  1  4  1  1  2
  1  4  3  4  3
  3  1  1  1  1
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not really allows to do that.

But you can use the following simple trick:

```
idx=find(B==0);
B(idx) = 1;
my_function(B); 
B(idx) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be concerned about the memory consumption, the short answer is - no. Matlab uses explicit index variables for about everything. What others suggested before:

```
idx = find(B==0)
```

silently allocates a matrix of `size(B)` logical values for the expression `B==0`. Depending on the matlab version, `logical` type may be 4 bytes or 1 byte, which saves you some memory compared to creating a copy of B:

```
A = B;
```

However, `find` again returns an array of `doubles`. Hence, depending on how many non-zero entries you actually have in `B`, you may end up using a lot of RAM: you need the memory  to store `B==0`, **and** the memory to store the result of `find` **at the same time**.

So, depending on your problem, it may be actually cheaper memory-wise to just to a copy of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to retain a copy of the original B, then you will have to make a second variable. Either duplicate it as you are doing, or replace the 0s with 1s after storing the indices to those elements in a second variable, i.e.

```
idx    = find(B==0);
B(idx) = 1;
```

If `numel(idx)` is considerably smaller than `numel(B)`, then that would save you some memory overhead if that's your concern.